# How property can be accessed through self key in php?

Tags: php, class

How variable can be accessed through self key in php? This program gives an Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: `self_test::$v in C:\webworks\phplab\test.php`

```
class self_test {

    public $v =10;

    public  function __construct(){
        echo self::$v;
    }
}   
new self_test();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$v` should be static.

```
<?php
class self_test {

public static $v =10;

public  function __construct(){

    echo self::$v;

}
}

new self_test();

?>
```